# MS SQL: Maximum / Cap on Unique ID / Unique Key? -OR- best way to reset key

Tags: sql-server, database

I currently have nightly schtasks / cron jobs that delete all entries in a database table and dump updated data into said table.  Understandably, the unique id / key for each row increments with each nightly delete and update.  The database is running on MS SQL Server.

My question: will the unique key ever hit a maximum / cap at some point in the future?  Or maybe, should I not worry about that question and simply reset the unique key as part of every nightly schtasks job?  Note: The key is NOT being used as a foreign key, so it is OK to reset it.

Is this the recommended SQL command to reset the key?: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Comment: I should have asked before I answered, but what's the data type for your id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use truncate instead of delete, the unique id / key will auto reset to beginning, so you don't need to worry about it.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TableName
```

See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx for details

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is, it depends.

The standard primary key is usually written something like this:

```
PK_ID int identity(1, 1) primary key
```

This primary key will start it's like at the number `1` and max out at `2,147,483,647`.  Depending on how fast your logs are growing, it could take years to reach this, or just days.  You will need to figure out how fast the data is growing and do some math to determine how quickly you will approach this number.

Another way to extend the life of an int primary key is to create it like this:

```
PK_ID int identity(-2,147,483,648, 1) primary key
```

This will start the primary key at the lowest possible value for an int, and grow to the highest possible value.  This doubles your room for growth.  However, be aware that there may be logic in your application that checks that the id > 0 to ensure that there is a record, so this may cause issues.

An alternative is to use the data type `bigint`.  It goes from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` (-9.22 * 10^18) to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (9.22 * 10^18).

The last standard option in SQL Server is to use a `guid`, or `uniqueidentifier`.  The total number of guids is about 5.31*10^36.

So, the answer is, you have to figure out how long it will take you to reach the maximum in these different scenarios, and determine which one is best for you.  You should also take into account how important the id of the record is.  If it's not important at all, then using an int and truncating the table may be enough.  If the id IS important, well, you have more research to do.